# Multidimensional array reshape with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I've been stuck on this numpy operation for a while now. I have an `np.array` of `np.shape` (x, y, z) that I want to make into an array of `np.shape` (y, x, z). I am having a hard time understanding the order on which `np.reshape` is done. For instance, I would like the values to be grouped by their index in the 2nd dim, and not on the first dimension.

For example, with this array of `np.shape` (3, 2, 9):

```
[[[-25 -25  15 -26 -26   0 -26 -26   3]
  [ -8  -2   0 -21  -9  39 -14 -11   2]]

 [[-25   2  18 -26 -10  10 -26 -15  14]
  [ -8  -2   0 -21  -9  39 -14 -11   2]]

 [[-25   2  18 -26 -10  14 -26 -15   5]
  [ -8  -2   3 -21  -9  18 -14 -11   3]]]
```

I would like the output of `np.shape` (2,3,9) to be:

```
[[[-25 -25  15 -26 -26   0 -26 -26   3]
  [-25   2  18 -26 -10  10 -26 -15  14]
  [-25   2  18 -26 -10  14 -26 -15   5]]

 [[ -8  -2   0 -21  -9  39 -14 -11   2]
  [ -8  -2   0 -21  -9  39 -14 -11   2]
  [ -8  -2   3 -21  -9  18 -14 -11   3]]]
```

And not :

```
[[[-25 -25  15 -26 -26   0 -26 -26   3]
  [ -8  -2   0 -21  -9  39 -14 -11   2]
  [-25   2  18 -26 -10  10 -26 -15  14]]

 [[ -8  -2   0 -21  -9  39 -14 -11   2]
  [-25   2  18 -26 -10  14 -26 -15   5]
  [ -8  -2   3 -21  -9  18 -14 -11   3]]]
```

I know this is basic numpy but so far every combination of `order='F'`, `array.T`, etc got me no luck. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Could you provide an example with integers instead of floats? It's very difficult to quickly recognize which floats correspond to which others.

Comment: Separately, is your goal to exchange the first and second dimensions, rather than reshaping the array?

Comment: Sure I edited with integers. That's the goal yes. Is there another function than np.reshape to do this kind of operation ?

Comment: I think @Akaisteph7's answer below should do it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `swapaxes`:

```
np.swapaxes(x,0,1) #x is your array
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's it.

Comment: For readablity, I'd almost even recommend `np.einsum` for cases like this, even though you're not doing any summing.  `np.einsum('ijk->jik', x)`

Comment: @DanielF I think it's much clearer with `np.swapaxes` what the goal is here. But it's great to have alternatives!